# Xamarin voice command by car

Tags: xamarin, voice-recognition

I'm looking for the best approach to implement voice command in a Xamarin app.
Here are my requirements:

- I don't need to launch my app by voice. Instead, my users will launch the app through touch (so, when the app is not running, no voice recognition is needed by my app)
- My app is a client/server app and it will work always on (the backend will run on [azure](/questions/tagged/azure))
- My app will be used primarily by car (so consider environment noise)
- My app will work in many languages, such as Italian, Spanish, French and English
- My app should be developed with [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin) (and eventually [mvvmcross](/questions/tagged/mvvmcross) or similar)
- In my app there will be two kinds of voice commands:

  1. to select an item from a short list: app will show a list of items, such as "apple, kiwi, banana and strawberry" and user will have to say one of those words.
  2. to change current view. Typically these voice commands will be something like "cancel", "confirm", "more" and stuff like these

The **typical interaction between user, app and server** should be this:

1. user says one of the available commands in current view/activity/page

   - suppose here that the user perfectly knows which commands he/she can use, it does no matter now how he/she knows these commands (he/she *just* knows them)
   - user could put before the commands some special words, such as "hey '*appname*'", to have a command like "hey 'appname', confirm"

     - Note: the "hey '*appname*'" part of the voice command has the only purpose to allow the app to know when the command starts. The app can be always in listening mode, but has to avoid to send the audio stream continuously to the server to recognize commands
2. best case is if app would recognize these commands locally, without involve the remote server, since the voice commands are predefined and well-known in each view. Anyway, app can send the audio wave to the server which will return a string (in this example the text returned will be "confirm", since the audio was "hey '*appname*', confirm")
3. app will map the text recognized with the available commands, and will invoke the right one
4. user will receive a feedback by the app. The feedback could be:

   - voice feedback (text-to-speech)
   - visual feedback (something on the screen)
   - both above

I was looking for [azure-cognitive-services](/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-services), but in this case, as far as I've understood, there is no way to recognize the start of the command locally (everything works on server side through REST api or clients). So the user would have to press a button before every voice command, and I need to avoid this kind of interaction.
Since the app is running, my user has him/her hands on the steering wheel, and he/she can't touch everytime the display. Isn't it?

Moreover, I was looking for [cortana-skills-kit](/questions/tagged/cortana-skills-kit) and [botframework](/questions/tagged/botframework), but:

1. It seems that Cortana Skills are available in English only
2. Actually, I don't need to involve Cortana to launch my app

I don't have experiences on these topics, so, hope that my question is clear and, generally speaking, that can be useful for other newbie users as well.

## *** UPDATE 1 ***

The Speech Recognition with the Voice Command Definition (VCD) file is really close to what I'd need, because:

- it has a way to activate the command through a command name shortcut
- It works in foreground (and background as well, even if in my case I don't need the background)

Unfortunately, this service works only on Windows, since it uses the local API. Maybe the right approach could be based on the following considerations:

- Every platform exposes a local speech recognition api (Cortana, Siri, Google Now)
- Xamarin exposes Siri and Google Now apis and make them available through C#
- It would be useful to create a *facade* component to expose the three different local speech api through a common interface

I'm wondering if there is something other solution to this. Cortana, as personal assistant, is available on Windows, iOS and Android. Since Cortana works both with local api and with remote service (Cortana Skills), is Cortana the right approach? Has Cortana the support for many languages (or, at least, has the support a road map)?
So, just some thoughts here. If you have some other ideas, or suggestions, please add here. Thanks